# Get the filename from stacktrace and frame when throw an exception

Tags: c#, stack-trace

I tried to get the filename and sourceline number when an exception is thrown.
But I got nothing.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException exception)
        {
            var stackTrace = new StackTrace(exception);
            var currentFrame = stackTrace.GetFrame(0);
            var fileName = currentFrame.GetFileName();
            var sourceLineNumber = currentFrame.GetFileLineNumber();
            Console.WriteLine("File Name: " + fileName);
            Console.WriteLine("Source line number: " + sourceLineNumber);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

There is only one frame is available. So I use the index 0 in `GetFrame(index)`.

Comment: I do think you should inspect the `exception` object's [`StackTrace` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.stacktrace(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

Comment: I would just do Console.WriteLine( exception.Message + " " + exception.StackTrace)`

Comment: [The documentation of the c'tor you are calling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25h0kw08(v=vs.100).aspx) says: **The StackTrace is created with the caller's current thread, and does not contain file name, line number, or column information.**

Comment: Do you really need the filename and line number from the stack trace or would having[`CallerFilePath` and `CallerLineNumber`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh534540.aspx) as attributes of a function you call be ok?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would write a method and use `CallerFilePath`, `CallerLineNumber` and `CallerMemberName` attributes

```
public void Log([CallerFilePath]string path="",[CallerLineNumber]int lineNumber=0,[CallerMemberName] string memberName="")
{
    Console.WriteLine(path + " " + lineNumber + " " + memberName);
}
```

Usage: `Log()`

For more Info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh534540.aspx