# Get file name instead of controller name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I use this line of code for error handling:

```
      catch (Exception exception)
      {
string controllerAction = $@"{ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString()}Controller/{ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString()}";
        iCommCommon.CommWeb.WriteLog("<ERR>", CommUser.piUSER_KEY, controllerAction, exception.Message + "\n" + (exception.InnerException != null ? exception.InnerException.Message : ""));
      }
```

String controllerAction gives me controller name / action name.

I would like to have file name where controller is saved, instead of controller name.

So, instead of:

```
HomeController
```

I would like to log:

```
HomeController.cs
```

And have controllerAction returning something like:

```
HomeController.cs/MyAction
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You can query the call stack using reflection and get the details from that

Comment: perhaps you have example in code for this?

Comment: See this answer for details. I highly recommend using the compile time attributes as sometimes the stack trace will be victim of inlining. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31518803/get-the-filename-from-stacktrace-and-frame-when-throw-an-exception

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best way to do it is to use the compiler services attributes that were added in .net 4.0.

```
public void Log([CallerFilePath]string path="",[CallerLineNumber]int lineNumber=0,[CallerMemberName] string memberName="")
{
    Console.WriteLine(path + " " + lineNumber + " " + memberName);
}
```

Shamelessly stolen from this answer. Upvote it! [Get the filename from stacktrace and frame when throw an exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31518803/get-the-filename-from-stacktrace-and-frame-when-throw-an-exception)

I highly recommend using these attributes whenever you need to extract information from the current frame. Occasionally, the runtime will 'in line's calls to smaller methods to improve performance. Properties suffer the most. These attributes inject the information in at compile time, so even if the call is inlined, the information is preserved.

Comment: If you're going to "shamelessly steal" another answer, why not just vote to close as a dupe?

Comment: Mainly because I have added more information than the linked answer. There is a lot of precedence for lifting snippets from other answers on SO. If you don't like it, downvote or flag it.

Comment: Then add details on the other question, not here.

Comment: Please show me the documentation for that behaviour.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled/

Answer (score 1):

One simple way I can imagine is just by appending the ".cs" since you are already appending the word Controller like that

```
    public string getFormattedRoute()
    {
        StringBuilder _strBldUri = new StringBuilder();
        _strBldUri.Clear();
        _strBldUri.Append(ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["controller"]);
        _strBldUri.Append("Controller");
        _strBldUri.Append(".cs/");
        _strBldUri.Append(ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["action"]);
        return _strBldUri.ToString();
    }
```

And use it like that

```
   catch (Exception exception)
  {
       string controllerAction = getFormattedRoute();
       iCommCommon.CommWeb.WriteLog("<ERR>", CommUser.piUSER_KEY, controllerAction, exception.Message + "\n" + (exception.InnerException != null ? exception.InnerException.Message : ""));
  }
```

Comment: This is not guaranteed to work, the filename doesn't necessarily match the class name.

Comment: I don't understand the case. Since he is talking about getting the Controller name from the route data is there a case where the controller will be in file that isn't a class? Or are you referring to a more general approach? I

Comment: I'm saying that it's only convention that a class is in a file with a matching name, but it's not always the case. How about partial classes for example?